# Euler's method example: Where this value came from?

Tags: numerical-methods, numerical-calculus, eulers-method

So, i've found an example that suits what i want to do, and i understood the majority of it, but i didn't really figured out where the last value, of the last line came from.

I wanna know where did they take the last temperature value from, the -26,099ºC at the end.

Here's a print of the example in question (i've drawn a arrow at the end to point out what i'm talking about):

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nloxA.jpg)

Thanks for anyone who can help me out! Have a great day!

Comment: The graph right next to the value?

Answer (score 1):

Let me just tell you... Those are crazy time steps! I would begin in the smallest time step they have considered and would decrease it until no change was observable in the ouput variable. Regarding your question, they are indicating the final temperature, obtained for the smallest time step.

Comment: Yeah but it is only for demonstration purposes. I will not use this method on a real application, just for na example, as i've said in the other post. And about this question: I've tried using a smaller time step, but not the smallest possible. I've used 25415 seconds and got -26,09956677 as my temperature value in return.